# How do I prevent a bitmap variable taking up too much memory when initializing it in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bitmap

I'm making a screen recording program so how it works is that it take a lot of pictures then stores them to make it into a video, but i ran into a problem when making the program run longer than 8 seconds. It uses way more memory than it should.

```
            while (DateTime.Now.Minute * 60000 + DateTime.Now.Second * 1000 + DateTime.Now.Millisecond < startTime+20000) {
            memoryImage = new Bitmap(ScreenBounds.Width, ScreenBounds.Height);
            // Create graphics 
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Graphics...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);

            // Copy data from screen 
            Console.WriteLine("Copying data from screen...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            try
            {
                    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, ScreenBounds);
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error when copying data from screen error: " + er.Message + " : breaking script");
                    break;
            }

            // Save it! 
            Console.WriteLine("Saving the image...");
            images.Add(memoryImage);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
```

As you can see I tried forcing garbage collection; the problem variable is memoryImage or at least that's what it seems to be I'm not completely sure. How can I get this program to use less memory, so it doesn't crash?

UPDATE:
I added memoryImage.Dispose(); to the end of the first part which fixed the memory issue but now I get the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

in this block of code:

```
            VideoWriter video = new VideoWriter(@"outputVideo.avi", (int)AvgFPSList.Average(), Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, true);
        for (int x = 0; x < images.Count; x++)
        {
            Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, Byte>(images[x]); << error here
            video.Write(img.Mat);
        }
```

Comment: You won't be able to keep all the frames in memory at once.

Comment: You'll have a hard time storing more than 100 or so bitmaps at once (depending on the size of the screen).  You can sometimes store a few more storing them as `byte[]` with the image encoded as JPG; even more if you thumbnail them to 740p or smaller.  Otherwise, save them to a thread safe collection and let a background worker save them somewhere for final processing later.

Comment: You don't say what type `images` is, but `images.Add()` sounds as if it either keeps a reference to the bitmap (in which case the bitmap can't be garbage collected) or it makes a copy of it (in which case you'll still be using just as much memory).  From the sounds of it calling `Dispose()` overrode that but then when you try to make the video the bitmaps you're making it from no longer exist.

Comment: Why are you saving all the frames and calling `video.Write` later rather than calling `video.Write` on each frame as it is created?

Comment: ok @Harry that makes sense I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question for future viewers,

The Graphics class implements IDisposable. To remove it from memory either wrap it in a using statement or manually call Dispose on it when you are finished using it.

Using example:

```
using (Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage))
{
    // perform operations on memoryGraphics
}
```

Bitmap also implements IDisposable and should be properly disposed of at some point.

The authors update of the question may be a different problem.